# how to fetch rows in sql server based on values of column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
id      dept         Person       Rating
-------------------------------------------
1       ece            p1           R1  
2       ece            p2           t1
3       eee            P3           R2             
4       eee            p4           M
5       Civil          P5           R2
6       Civil          P6           t2
7       Civil          P7           t2
8       Mech           p8           R2
9       Mech           P9           NULL
10      IT             P10          R2J
11      IT             P11          T2
12      IT             P12          T2
```

I would like to fetch all the rows whose department's rating has at least one value like 'P%' and one like 'T%'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather direct method uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.dept = t.dept and t2.rating like 'P%') and
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.dept = t.dept and t2.rating like 'T%') ;
```

Comment: @vishal . . . That is a correlation clause that does the comparisons over rows with the same department.

Comment: .Why we are selecting 1 "select 1" ?

Comment: @vishal . .  `exists` is only checking for the existence of a row.  Generally, a row needs to have *some* value.  I find that `1` is the easiest thing to type.

Comment: select * from table_name (nolock) where (rating like 'P%') or (rating like 'T%')

Comment: @Gordon Linoff.I would like to fetch all the rows whose department's rating has at least one value like 'T%' and does not have like 'P%'.          I tried              
 select t.*
      from t
     where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.dept = t.dept and t2.rating not like 'P%') and
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.dept = t.dept and t2.rating like 'T%') ;                  But Unable to get desired results.